# Qlik sense vizlib Writeback table - how to set options in data load editor and use "Options Field" in drop down

Tags: qliksense

I have a Writeback table where I would like to use drop downs and set the options for the drop down in the Data Load editor. I'm some cases I have up to 30 drop down options and they might change over time so setting them in the DLE would be much easier than listing them out one by one.

I thought I saw how to do this here :https://community.vizlib.com/support/solutions/articles/35000156684-vizlib-writeback-table-propertie... but I can't seem to get the options to populate in the drop down. I have not found documentation on this besides this link.

I am especially confused on what to put for "Options Field Separator" (I'm not even sure what this means).

This is what I have so far:

DLE:
[image]

Qlik:
[image]

When I used "dimension" instead of creating a column, it created 3 separate rows in the table-one for each value-rather drop down options. When I tried separating the options in the DLE using semicolon instead of commas it still did not work.

Any help would be much appreciated! My table is going to have A LOT of drop downs with many options so being able to easily define them in the DLE is essential.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried writing your INLINE LOAD statement without any punctuation mark? Comma is generally used to separate the columns, rather than adding a new value in a single column, which is what you need here.

Example inline statement for a single column:

```
tableA:
load * inline[
columnA
1
2
3
4];
```

Above statement generates a table called *tableA* with single column called *columnA* and 4 rows.